# how can I prevent my custom element from getting its own div?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have created a custom C# object that inherits [ScriptControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptcontrol.aspx) and [INamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx). All it has are some spans inside.
When I place it on my page, it gets its own div, which I don't want. Is there a property or something I can set to force it to be created as a span instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey
 {
     get 
     {
          // return elmement that you would like  HtmlTextWriterTag.Span for instance.
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could override protected [`TagKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tagkey.aspx) property of your control; it gets the `HtmlTextWriterTag` value that corresponds to this Web server control:

```
protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey
{
    get { return HtmlTextWriterTag.Span; }
}
```